# Returning a properly formatted recursive list in Python

Tags: python, recursion

This is homework that has been breaking my head and I was wondering if someone could help me understand where I am going wrong. Essentially, I have my two strings, "a" and "b". If "a" or "b" is empty, I return the other string, otherwise, I return the union of, the first character in each string plus the recursive call on the rest of each string. Therefore this screams recursion at me, so I build the following function.

```
def myFunction(s, t):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return([t])
    if len(t) == 0:
        return([s])
    else:
        to_add = [[s[0]] + (myFunction(s[1:], t)), ([t[0]] + myFunction(s, t[1:]))]
        return(to_add)
```

which prints when the function is called with inputs s = "ab" and t= "cd":

```
[['a', ['b', 'cd'], ['c', ['b', 'd'], ['d', 'b']]], ['c', ['a', ['b', 'd'], ['d', 'b']], ['d', 'ab']]]
```

So as far as I can see, this isn't really a logic issue, more of I'm being a bit silly with how I'm returning my code, because the answer I'm expecting is in there, just within a bunch of lists within lists. The answer I'm expecting is:

['abcd', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cdab']

If someone could point out where I'm being really silly/suggest a better way of doing this I'd be very thankful, cause I'm starting to feel really bad about this haha.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expected output? Also, your function isn't recursive, and you do not define `shuffle` (is this `random.shuffle`?).

Comment: The description is unclear. You say you're given strings, but then you say you're supposed to return the union of lists. Are they lists or strings?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what "I return the union of the two lists" is supposed to mean. Can you provide example inputs/expected outputs? That usually helps clarify

Comment: Why are you shuffling the lists, what does that have to do with returning a union? The problem description is leaving out lots of details.

Comment: Are you just trying to write a recursive definition of `union`?

Comment: My bad, I definitely messed this up with some bad copy and paste errors. I've edited in my test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you're giving as the expected answer looks more like every possible combination of the strings `s` and `t` keeping the characters from `s` and `t` in the result in the order they were in in `s` and `t`.

To achieve that in a simple generator function:

```
def combine(s, t):
    if not s:
        yield t
    elif not t:
        yield s
    else:
        for tail in combine(s[1:], t):
            yield s[0] + tail
        for tail in combine(s, t[1:]):
            yield t[0] + tail


print(list(combine('ab', 'cd')))
```

Result:

```
['abcd', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cdab']
```

Comment: Basically you explained my problem better than I did haha, thanks for that. You are very correct, thank you very much :)